# How to duplicate a node in a particular chef_environment

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

I have an existing chef node :

```
Node Name:   app1
Environment: DEMO
FQDN:        el-demo-app1
IP:          xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Run List:    recipe[yum_el2], role[Dep], recipe[crypto], role[mule-server], role[activemq], recipe[tomcat-conf], role[tomcat]
Roles:       activemq, tomcat
Recipes:     yum_el, crypto, yum, java, activemq, tomcat-conf, el_conf::commonservices, java::oracle,iptables::default
Platform:    redhat 6.6
Tags:
```

how do i make another node identical to this one in another environment named LOCAL

I downloaded the run-list from the node app1 to a local json file as far as the recipes and roles , they seem to be in the git repo already, then, do i upload them to the chef server ? and then apply them to the node ? do i do the same for data-bags ( from environment = DEMO ), which have keys

```
What i WAS able to do is to:
1. download a recipe from supermarket
   - knife cookbook site search ack
   - knife cookbook site download ack 
2. add it to git in my branch
   git add ack , in the cookbooks folder
3. upload that to the chef server
   - knife cookbook upload ack
4. apply that as a run-list
   - sudo chef-client --runlist "ack"
and it worked
5. test it
   $ack --help
```

the current node which needs to be identical to node app1 looks like:

```
$ knife search node chef_environment:LOCAL
1 items found

Node Name:   dt-linux-dev111
Environment: LOCAL
FQDN:        dt-linux-dev111
IP:          yy.yyy.yyy.yyy
Run List:    recipe[nodejs]
Roles:
Recipes:     nodejs, nodejs::default, environment_elis2::default, nodejs::packages
Platform:    redhat 6.7
Tags:
```

Question:

Can i apply the same steps to "Roles", Recipes" and "data-bags" as i did for "Run-list" ? which is looking at the array structure of the Roles and add it , doing a "knife node edit dt-linux-dev111", appending the required Roles and Recipes, as well as data-bags, then running a sudo chef-client

```
How do i add multiple roles to a node?

How do i add multiple Recipes to a node ?

How do i add multiple data-bags to a node ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Role and recipes are collectively just run list entries, and you can "copy" them via `knife node edit` or any of the other knife commands that manipulate run lists. There is nothing specific for copying from one to another, just copy-pasta the array of strings. The `Roles:` and `Recipes:` values in the knife output will be updated after you run `chef-client` successfully at least once, they are cached output from the last run (as are most values stored in the node data).

Data bags are not attached to a particular node or environment, they are global objects so there is no interaction here.

Answer (score 0):

Use roles and environments, don't duplicate nodes. Just create environments and nodes and assign them to specific nodes. That's recommended approach. If you already have configuration assigned to a node, move it to a role and/or environment.